# Encrypting PII + other data in RDS Database With AWS KMS & Secrets Manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-rds, aws-secrets-manager, amazon-kms

### My needs - Read/Write Encrypted Data

I have a software application that can build webpages and emails and I need to encrypt content stored in the database (PII plus user generated content by financial/healthcare institutions).

I would like to use AWS KMS/AWS Secrets Manager to manage the `hash` so the `hash` is secured and keys that gate the `hash` are automatically rotated and managed by AWS. I'll use this `hash` to encrypt/decrypt data. Two way encryption is required.

### My Question

It seems there are two options, and I'm not sure which is preferred and which is the proper way to use AWS for this:

##### Option 1 - Encrypt DB Access (Not preferred)

I could store all PII and encrypted data in a separate RDS DB, and simply gate API access with encryption provided by AWS Secrets Manger and KMS. This kinda stinks because the encrypted data relates to tables in the main DB. So hosting this data elsewhere is cumbersome to maintain.

##### Option 2 - Encrypt the data on a field level (!Preferred!)

I would prefer to store encrypted data in the DB directly. For instance a table may have 7 columns unencrypted, but the `content` column contains encrypted data. I then need to figure out a way to encrypt/decrypt this securely. I would need some sort `hash` that encrypts/decrypts the data. Storing in directly in PHP seems like a bad idea so could I use AWS KMS / Secrets Manager to do this?

**Plan A** -
I store a `hash` in Secrets Manager (Encrypted with KMS), so when the application wants to  encrypt/decrypt content, it uses the required IAM user to get the hash from AWS Secrets Manager, encrypts/decrypts the content and then removes the `hash` from memory.

**Plan B*** -
I use KMS directly (No secrets manager) and pass encrypted/decrypted content to KMS directly and it encrypts/decrypts on the fly, never needing to expose or send the key it's using to perform these actions.

---

Thanks again for taking the time

Comment: What is the invariant of what data can't touch what else?  The obvious solution would be to move the entire DB to an RDS database where the entire thing is encrypted by KMS transparently for you, but it appears to be something you did not consider.  Is your primary DB not able to move to RDS?

Comment: Sorry, to be clear our DBs are all already on RDS currently. So everything is encrypted natively. The problem is some content we need encrypted (salted technically I think) so it's not human readable in the DB. That way we can track requests to decrypt that information in CloudTrail. So the field level encryption is needed on DB columns throughout the RDS DB.

Comment: I see, the audit trail of access to the fields is what is important.  Two more pieces of information I need to recommend a course: What is the largest than an individual field can get to in size?  Do you need individual field access tracked separately or at the column level (like user A accessed records 1, 4, and 18 of column 'X' or is it just sufficient that user A accessed elements of column 'X' in the protected table)?